# Where i can find ftp credentials for azure web app linux?

Tags: azure

I would access the content of my linux app on azure using ftp but i dont know where find the ftp credentials.

In the deployment center i cannot find any ftp section, instead i get some informations on git distribution.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you previously set Git deployment for this Web App and this is why the UI defaults to Git.  If you don't need it anymore, simply click on Disconnect.  This way you can select and set FTP deployments again in Deployment Center.

You can also get the FTP URL from the Overview tab but what about the FTP credentials?  Simply click on the Get Publish Profile link, they are in the XML file that will be downloaded.